# What is the difference between the Scale of Interest & Scale of Estimation

Tags: multiple-regression, scales

As an example of the distinction I have yet to fully parse, consider this (I am not interested in the specific content, it just happens to be a common hit when searching for "scale of interest")

> We investigate how the scale of estimation in risk-adjustment models
> for health-care costs affects the covariate effect, where the scale of
> interest for the covariate effect may be different from the scale of
> estimation. As an illustrative example, we use claims data to estimate
> the incremental costs associated with heart failure within one year
> subsequent to myocardial infarction. Here, the scale of interest for
> the effect of heart failure on costs is additive. However, traditional
> methods for modeling costs use predetermined scale of estimation – for
> example, ordinary least squares (OLS) regression assumes an additive
> scale while log-transformed OLS and generalized linear models with
> log-link assume a multiplicative scale of estimation

(Basu, Anirban, Bhakti V. Arondekar, and Paul J. Rathouz. ‘Scale of Interest versus Scale of Estimation: Comparing Alternative Estimators for the Incremental Costs of a Comorbidity’. Health Economics 15, no. 10 (October 2006): 1091–1107. https://doi.org/10.1002/hec.1099.)

**The question is**: what is the difference between the scale of interest and the scale of estimation? (Especially since the last sentence uses "scale of estimation" in a way that does not seem different from the previous use of "scale of interest" to me).

The more precise the distinction the better.